# Hi-res versions of Bing daily images?

Tags: bing

Is there a repository somewhere of the daily images used on the Bing homepage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some related to your question is given in the below link:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-a-bing-wallpaper-desktop-slideshow-in-windows-7/

Comment: Noting: This is a Windows OS-specific solution. There are homebrew solutions for other OS wallpapers from Bing. Just noting here so you don't waste time if you aren't on Windows!

Answer (score 1):

This is an official desktop wallpaper feed that is hi-resolution.  Nice and easy to install as well.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/bing-dynamic-theme

Comment: This question is practically 2 years old, just FYI...  The official theme will work, but it is only "the best of."  If you want all of the images you'll need to use the fix kamleshrao linked to.

Comment: This is also just for Windows OS, and isn't a general solution. If you have Windows there are several nice solutions ; I'm on Mac and have installed bing-wallpaper which takes a little doing.

Answer (score 1):

This website has daily Bing daily images:

http://binghomepagewallpapers.x10host.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can download high-res wallpapers from Bing from a few places in HD, including https://www.hi-res.pics/bing1920x1200 (non-OS-specific solution).

Comment: Note: "High res" means 1920×1200. Not 1440p or above.

Comment: Yep, the solutions there were originally available in 1920x1200 but I see the URLs no longer resolve. Sorry about that. Updated with a new solution.